# Enabling Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS) for LitS3

Tags: mono, amazon-s3

I've switched from Affirma.ThreeSharp to LitS3 for get/put file access to Amazon S3 using Mono and C#. I can upload/download files with the ACL rights I want. However, I can't set the Reduced Redundancy Storage property using LitS3. Has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First modify **S3Headers.cs** by adding the following:

```
public const string ReducedRedundancyStorage = "x-amz-storage-class";
```

Next,modify **AddObject.cs** by changing the **Authorize()** method to include the following:

```
WebRequest.Headers[S3Headers.ReducedRedundancyStorage] = "REDUCED_REDUNDANCY";
```

That seems to do it.